# Get data on daily basis in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have mysql table which is having earnings records with date. i want to get total earning  on daily ,weekly and monthly basis.

I tried to get these records on basis of date but is confusing.

i want to get these reports on daily , weekly and monthly basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing Laravel cron job scheduling to fulfill your specific requirement.

Please refer following Laravels official  documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs

I'll show a simple example to get an idea about this configuration.

```
php artisan make:command DailyUpdate
```

above command will create a class component in the following location 
app/Console/Commands directory.

Generated class file will be similar to below,

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class DailyUpdate extends Command

{

   /**

    * The name and signature of the console command.

    *

    * @var string

    */

   protected $signature = 'command:name';



   /**

    * The console command description.

    *

    * @var string

    */

   protected $description = 'Command description';



   /**

    * Create a new command instance.

    *

    * @return void

    */

   public function __construct()

   {

       parent::__construct();

   }



   /**

    * Execute the console command.

    *

    * @return mixed

    */

   public function handle()

   {

       //

   }

}
```

After that change the following according to your requirement.

```
protected $signature = 'command:name';
protected $description = ‘Command description’;
```

Inside the  handle() you can place the implementation that you need to repeat on a scheduled basis.

```
public function handle() {
     // implementation
}
```

After all the changes, you need to register that command.

In app/console/kernal.php change the configuration as follows,

```
protected $commands = [
       Commands\DailyUpdate::class
   ];




protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
   {
       $schedule->command('hour:update')
                ->daily();
   }
```

Comment: Actually there is different attributes in table. price ,date etc. if there is multiple records on same date then it should calculate sum of it. otherwise it should return as it is. i think there should be any query  for this